# 'LpVariable' object does not support indexing

Tags: for-loop, optimization, constraints, pulp

I ran into the error of 'LpVariable' object does not support indexing. Is this due to how my data are being setup for my PuLP optimization?

Basically, I am trying to get the optimized sales by multiplying the replenishment quantity with the selling price for each SKU (UPC). The replenishment quantity will be based on the quantity sold (available in the dataset) and will be the constraint for the optimization problem. I should not replenish way too much than what I sold.

Could someone with PuLP experience please help me with my error? Is the way I setup my For-Loop logical?

---

Here is the key portion of my Python codes:
After sorting my data based on LocationNumber, the first and last few rows of my data are as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ5IN.png)

```
df.drop(['LowlawWeekYear'], axis=1, inplace=True) # Drop the WeekYear column

store_list = {108} # This is LocationNumber. Will only run one store for now

for store_number in sorted(store_list):
  specific_store = df[df['LocationNumber'] == store_number] 
  Qty_Price_df = specific_store.groupby('UPC', as_index = False)['AvgSellingPricewoTax', 'Units'].mean()

# get the mean of the AvgSellingPricewoTax and Units. Ultimately, I only need one row for each UPC with the average values of AvgSellingPricewoTax and Units.

SKU_list = sorted(list(set(Qty_Price_df.UPC))) # List of SKU numbers

Variable_list = dict(zip(Qty_Price_df.UPC, Qty_Price_df.UPC)) # Variables which I am looking to optimize

Price_list = dict(zip(Qty_Price_df.UPC, Qty_Price_df.AvgSellingPricewoTax))

Qty_list = dict(zip(Qty_Price_df.UPC, Qty_Price_df.Units)) # Quantity sold per UPC. This will be used in the constraint.

from pulp import *

optimization = LpProblem("Perfect_Store", LpMaximize)

Variable_list = LpVariable("SKU", lowBound=0) # Continuous by default

# Define objective function
optimization += lpSum([Price_list[type]*Variable_list[type] for type in SKU_list]), "Total Sales by multiplying Price with Variable Qty"
***# Here is where I ran into the error message: 'LpVariable' object does not support indexing***

# Set constraint for each SKU
for c in SKU_list:
  optimization += (Qty_list[c] <= Qty_list[c]*1.05), "Constraints for each SKU is the replenishment quantity which should not be more than 5% of the quantity sold"

print("Status:", LpStatus[optimization.status])
```

Comment: you need to use LpVariable.dicts if you want to use indices on your decision variable. what you have currently is not a decision variable list, as your variable name might suggest, but rather a single decision variable

Comment: Also your constraints are not using any decision variable but only parametric input. what are you trying to achieve with this constraint? seemingly this constraint will regardless of decision variable values always be true since 105% of any value is always greater than the value itself